# PayPal Express Checkout: CHECKOUTSTATUS=PaymentActionNotInitiated when calling GetExpressCheckoutDetails

Tags: express-checkout

Testing in the sandbox.

Making the following calls:

1. SetExpressCheckout
   2. GetExpressCheckoutDetails
2. DoExpressCheckoutPayment

When calling GetExpressCheckoutDetails, we are constantly receiving the following response:

CHECKOUTSTATUS=PaymentActionNotInitiated
ACK-Success

Most of what I've read states that this indicates that the customer isn't returning to the return URL. That is not the case and has been tested thoroughly.

We do have a '?' contained in the return URL to keep from having to create additional pages and am wondering if that might be an issue.

Can a returnurl for PayPal Express Checkout contain any characters e.g "?"

Example:
"https://example.com/payment_page?return&token=EC-7BX27754BT8623257&PayerID=UPGGM5VND8D5Q" 
as opposed to using
"https://example.com/payment_page_return?token=EC-7BX27754BT8623257&PayerID=UPGGM5VND8D5Q"?

Thanks,
KB

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately testing proved that the primary issue was **not** including minimum required parameters for each of the three calls - 1. SetExpressCheckout 2. GetExpressCheckoutDetails
3. DoExpressCheckoutPayment - each is outlined at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/ec-initiate-payment/

'?' in the URL was not an issue.